# Dyld warnings from using cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods, xcode7-beta3, xcode6.4

I received these warnings that have haunted me for two days.

```
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../lib in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework/Versions/A/../../../../Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libclang.dylib being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
dyld: warning, LC_RPATH @executable_path/../Frameworks in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/Xcode3Core being ignored in restricted program because of @executable_path
```

I was doing it with Xcode 7 beta, but then I realized it might be that cocoapods does not support Swift2 yet. So I started to reuse Xcode6. However, I am still receiving the same warnings. I believe that these warnings prevented me from importing frameworks into my swift files... Why would the program be restricted? Here is my thanks to anyone who have an idea about this issue.

Followup: So I shifted to Xcode6.4 and Swift1 but the problem still bugged me. I have also tried to reinstall cocoapods but it did not help.

Comment: any update on this, I am facing same issue with Xcode-beta4?

Comment: @tGilani so far there is none sadly... Which OS are you using, if I may ask? I'm using the public beta of el capitain and it seems even using the Xcode from App Store does not help as well.

Comment: yep, I am using public beta el capitan too...

Comment: @tGilani yea. I guess probably we just have to wait until cocoa pods do some updates..

Answer (score 0):

Until https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/3661 gets addressed, you can either disable bit code generation on your app 
or go to the target dependencies section of your target and set Pods.framework to required.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a system ruby issue and CocoaPods is working on that: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4121

It shouldn't affect the usage of the pods though, you can reinstall ruby to silence that.

Answer (score 0):

Updating CocoaPods to 0.39 fixes this issue. Use `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods` in El Capitan to install.

Comment: 0.39 has problems with RestKit: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4202